# maximum simultaneous watchdog instance

Tags: java, multithreading

i want to use a timeout observer like Apache's Watchdog.
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/util/Watchdog.java

Watchdog creates a thread for each timeout request. And all these threads are in waiting state until the timeout value. I want to create a socket server every connection uses a timeout observer for different states. 1000 connection means 1000 parallel timeout observer instance. Is this a big problem? Or Is number of threads in waiting state ignorable?